# HTML isn't updated by knockout in QUnit test

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, qunit

I'm writing unit tests with QUnit in order to test the HTML of a web page.
The webpage uses knockout to alter the DOM.
In the test, knockout isn't triggered or loaded, so the alteration it's supposed to do isn't done. Therefore, the test fails.

Index.cshtml

```
<script>
    QUnit.config.autostart = false;
</script>
<div id="qunit-fixture">
    <div id="root">
        <div class="board" data-bind="click: css: { 'selected': $data === $root.SelectedBoard() }">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/root.js"></script>
<script>
    var root = new Root();
    $(function ()
    {
        ko.applyBindings(root, document.getElementById('root'));
        QUnit.start(); //Tell QUnit we are ready to launch test
    }); 
</script>
```

Root.JS

```
Root = function ()
{
        var self = this;
        self.Boards = [];
        self.SelectedBoard = ko.observable(null);
        self.SelectBoard = function (board, event)
        {
            if (!!board && board != null && self.SelectedBoard() !== board)
            {
                self.SelectedBoard(board);
                self.SelectedBoard().LoadData();
            }
        };

        //Some stuff that build "Boards" array.
}
```

Test.js

```
test("Selected board have a visual indicator to display it.", 1, function ()
{
    var $Boards= $(".Board");
    root.SelectBoard(root.Boards[2]);//Does change root.SelectedBoard
    ok($Boards.eq(2).hasClass("selected"), "Second board should be selected");//Fail because knockout didn't add "selected" class yet.
});
```

**What can I change to have knockout work and make the modification it's supposed in the test?**

Note : 
The initial run of the test fails, but when I click "rerun" in  the QUnit interface, the test passes.

Comment: Tried to put a fiddle together but your code is incomplete...what is $tabPages? http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/RMh78/109/

Comment: @Luis, jsfiddle is complete now, but it do work in the fiddle. It also do in the website except for the first run that always fail. Like if knockout was sleeping or not ready during the first run.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RMh78/118/

Comment: So far, from what I read on the internet, the issue probably come from the fact that I doesn't apply the binding in QUnit.testStart()

Comment: Yeah, i have no idea it should work...dont know enough of QUnit to answer this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test wasn't working on first try because of the order tests were ran. Subsequent run worked because failed test are run in first. So, my test weren't independent from each other because I declared variable "root" only once and applied the knockout binding. Because of this, each test leave variable "root" in a different state for the next test to be run. Needless to say that this is bad.

To fix the issue, I used Qunit setup/teardown to create variable root and apply the knockout binding before each test.

```
setup: function ()
{
    var divRoot = $('#root')[0];
    this.root = new Root();
    ko.applyBindings(this.root, divRoot);

},
teardown: function ()
{
    var divRoot = $('#root')[0];
    ko.cleanNode(divRoot);
    this.root = null;
}
```

Everything work as expected with this. So the behavior of knockout was only a consequence of having dependent test.

Also, qunit-fixture reset the DOM after each test, so this might also have interfered with knockout when I had only one mapping for every tests.